# How to Create Insert Statement from Table Data using sp_export_data without Id?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to Create Insert Statement from Table Data using sp_export_data without the Id?
I have the following statements and want to **omit the Identity**. How would I accomplish this?

This is how I'm scripting the one row:

```
exec sp_export_data tblTableName
 , @from ="FROM tblTableName WHERE tblTableNameId = 123"
```

This is how I am script the whole table:

```
exec sp_export_data tblTableName
 , @from ="FROM tblTableName"
```

Any & all feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Create Insert Statement from Table Data using sp_export_data without the Id the syntax is:

```
sp_export_data tblTableName
, @ommit_identity = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with using a slightly different approach (still T-SQL) go to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065357/how-to-generate-an-insert-script-for-an-existing-sql-server-table-that-includes) and scroll down to the answer by Neeraj Prasad Sharma where he creates the stored procedure named INS.

Within that procedure you can add a where clause of something like table where id <> 1.  Here is some example code.

First create your table and test records.

```
CREATE TABLE testNegative
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,Col1 VARCHAR(200)
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.testNegative
        ( Col1 )
VALUES  ( 'test1' ), ( 'test2' ), ( 'test3' ), ( 'test4' ), ( 'test5' ) ;
GO
```

This will insert ID's 1-5 into the table.  Now say that I want to script out every row other than ID 1.   I would then run this:

```
EXEC INS ' dbo.testNegative where id <> 1';
```

This procedure has worked well for me in a number of scenarios.  I think it will do what you are looking for here.